# SageMathCloud: Error: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, eof, sage

In a Sage worksheet (.sagews file) in SageMathCloud, this code:

```
def elgamal_encrypt ( pub_key ,g ,p , message ):
k = floor ( 1+( p -2)* random ())
return ( Mod (g , p )^ k , message * Mod ( pub_key ^k , p ) )
```

produces the error:

```
Error in lines 1-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/7870d70a-93d1-44f4-bce4-990a540707b7/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py", line 879, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals

  File "<string>", line 1

    def elgamal_encrypt ( pub_key ,g ,p , message ):
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Does you code match the edit?

Comment: What is with the weird spacing? Not that Python cares, but it makes your code very difficult to read.

Comment: Although I quit the spacing I have the same error

Comment: @Tive Surrender: 1.  Give context. You wrote: << I don't understand where the error is. My code: [...] The error: [...] >> You could have written: << In a Sage worksheet (.sagews file) in SageMathCloud, this code [...] produces this error: [...] >>
2. In SageMathCloud, make the document where the error happens public, and give a link. Then people can see the code and the error, they can copy the document to their SageMathCloud account, and they can investigate the error in the same setting. See my comment to Dagrooms's answer.

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre Very good edit suggestion. Next time propose an edit to the question! (At this point I have spliced your comment into the question for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the `k=...` line.

```
def elgamal_encrypt ( pub_key ,g ,p , message ):
    k = floor ( 1+( p -2)* random ())
    return ( Mod (g , p )^ k , message * Mod ( pub_key ^k , p ) )
```

Note that the particular reason this happened to you is because you are on SageMathCloud -- see [this page](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/fc94de41-6af4-4ee1-a684-c33a9e56b2b0/files/2015-06-02-stackoverflow-30579552.sagews) for details on the error and fix. (Thanks to @Samuel Lelièvre in comments.)

Comment: While I agree, this mistake would produce an _`IndentationError`_, not an _`EOFError`_.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist: the error message reveals the code is run on SageMathCloud. Dagrooms's answer is correct. See this public worksheet on SageMathCloud for details: https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/fc94de41-6af4-4ee1-a684-c33a9e56b2b0/files/2015-06-02-stackoverflow-30579552.sagews

Comment: I stand corrected. I am not familiar with SageMathCloud and this particular idiosyncracy. Unfortunately I cannot reverse my DV without an edit to the answer. Edit: There. I put your link into the answer where it probably belongs anyway.